# Is it possible to select bluetooth audio codec in HFP profile?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hfp

By enabling developer options in Android,it is possible to change A2DP audio codec(SBC/aptx/aptxHD...).
In the similar manner, Is it possible to change bluetooth audio codec(CVSD/mSBC) in HFP profile as well?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is NO.
When either side HFP want to make an audio channel, the two side will negotiate at the time and based on the many factors and run-time conditions to chose a best fit.

Comment: In that case, do you have any suggestions on how to implement CVSD audio encoder and decoder algorithm?